# check XML node exists or not using javascript

Tags: javascript

How do check '**roster**' has no child values using javascript

```
<club code="3RD1" tvcode="">
   <name>3RD PLACE TEAM 1</name>
   <roster/>
</club>
<club code="3RD1" tvcode="">
   <name>3RD PLACE TEAM 1</name>
   <roster>
     <player code="AUQ"/>
   </roster>
</club>
```

Comment: Can you show your JavaScript effort?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you can use jquery,

you can parse this by using [$.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

```
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( "<xml></xml>" );
```

and then you can use `find` to get the prefered node

```
$(xmlDoc).find("roster")
```

and get number of children via

```
.children().length
```

putting it together

```
var rostersChildren = $(xmlDoc).find("roster").children().length;
console.log(rostersChildren > 0);
```

here is a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QNuPV/).